# PhpUnit form does not submit, no error

Tags: forms, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I'm doing a functional test in PhpUnit to test simple modal window functionality which has only one field and two buttons (i have tried various ways so the code may be not clean, I'm pasting just to show the idea):

```
    $form = $crawler
         // find all buttons with the text "Pridėti"
        ->filter('button:contains("Pridėti")') 
        ->eq(0)
        ->form()// select the first button in the list
    ;

    $form['appbundle_classinfo[name]'] = '5a';
    $crawler = $client->submit($form);

    //It doesn't even save to database 
    $container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
    $em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $classinfo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ClassInfo');

    //Echoes modal window
    echo $client->getResponse()->getContent() ;die;
```

I also tried to var_dump the form, it shows that the value is added to form:
string(25) "appbundle_classinfo[name]"
          ["value":protected]=>
          string(2) "5a"

So the form is not submitted. Can you help me find out why?

Comment: Have you checked the API? Does `form()` return an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class PostTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testShowPost()
    {
        //returns a Client, your browser use your web site
        $client = static::createClient();

         // The request() method (read more about the request method) returns a Crawler object which can be used to select elements in the response, click on links and submit forms.
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/your/route/controller/action');

        // select button by name or id
         $form = $crawler->selectButton('Login')->submit();

         //submit the form
         $crawler->submit($form);

         $this->assertGreaterThan(
             0,
             $crawler->filter('html:contains("hello world")')->count()
         );

        // get HTML content returned
        dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());

    }
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#functional-tests

hope that were useful, let me know.

Comment: The `$crawler` object does not have a `submit` method.